# Symfony doctrine self reference

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Is it possible to have self reference field in entity? Like so:

```
class Dir
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   protected $id;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
   protected $parent; // reference to other Dir
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this [chapter](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing) in Doctrine's documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between common association and self reference.

The following might work:

```
class Dir
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   private $id;

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dir")
    */
   private $parent;
}
```

Read more about associations in `Doctrine` [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html).

Also you should use `private` properties if you do not plan to inherit from your entity.